# NOT IN is not working in sybase?

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-iq

I have two table lets say **Table1** and **Table2**
and both table have a column Name and ID

I want to fetch all the name from **Table2** which is not in **Table1**
I have written below query :

```
Select Name,ID FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.Name NOT IN (Select t1.Name FROM Table1 t1);
```

but this query is not giving expected output, I mean it also gives me Name which is in **Table1**.

I done some google and found it could be if **Table1** have **null** values i.e. If sub-query result contain **null**. although my table doesn't have null values but for making sure this is not a problem I have rewritten query, but without ant luck:

```
Select Name,ID FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.Name 
NOT IN (Select t1.Name FROM Table1 t1 where t1.Name is not null);
```

Still I am not getting expected result but strangely some time it gives result as expected and some time not, any suggestion, help will be appreciated.

Is there any bug in sybase 16? I am using sybase 16 with db-visualizer.

**UPDATE**
If I have below data

### Table1

```
   Name        ID
-------------------
  Jay          1
---------------------
```

### Table2

```
   Name        ID
-------------------
  Jay          1
  Tom          2
---------------------
```

### Expected result

```
   Name        ID
-------------------
  Tom          2
---------------------
```

but I am getting :

### Result coming

```
   Name        ID
-------------------
  Jay          1
  Tom          2
---------------------
```

**Please note some time I am getting expected result too, not sure why some time it is working as expected and some time not**

Comment: Pls be a bit more specific as to what you mean by not getting the expected result! Provide sample data, expected output and the output provided by the 2nd query.

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data (as `insert into`) and what you expect to see.

Comment: Maybe you have some trailing spaces in one of the names. Try with `trim(name)` (or whatever the equivalent in Sybase is)

Comment: Very unlikely to be a bug in ASE 16, this is absolutely standard functionality; I used this type of query myself recently and it worked just fine. In the absence of an exact reproduction that others can also repro, I would assume there is something funny with your query.-- upper/owercase mismatches? Funny characters (e.g. CR or LF) in the data?